# gcp-cups-connector install archlinux arm

Tags: linux, archlinux, google-cloud-print

I've been trying for hours to get gcp-cups-connector installed on my ALARM system.

Here is the output from running mkpkg, following by the 'go env' to show my variables.

```
[nw@NWCloud go]$ makepkg -A
==> Making package: gcp-cups-connector 2015.09.30.r2.g149c605-1 (Sun Oct  4 23:11:10 MDT 2015)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Cloning gcp-cups-connector git repo...
Cloning into bare repository '/home/nw/go/gcp-cups-connector'...
remote: Counting objects: 1981, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
remote: Total 1981 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1940
Receiving objects: 100% (1981/1981), 740.91 KiB | 804.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1002/1002), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
  -> Cloning gcp-cc-service git repo...
Cloning into bare repository '/home/nw/go/gcp-cc-service'...
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
==> Validating source files with md5sums...
    gcp-cups-connector ... Skipped
    gcp-cc-service ... Skipped
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of cups-connector git repo...
Cloning into 'gcp-cups-connector'...
done.
  -> Creating working copy of gcp-cups-connector-systemd git repo...
Cloning into 'gcp-cc-service'...
done.
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Starting build()...
github.com/google/cups-connector (download)
cd .
git clone https://github.com/google/cups-connector /home/nw/go/src/src/github.com/google/cups-connector
cd /home/nw/go/src/src/github.com/google/cups-connector
git show-ref
cd /home/nw/go/src/src/github.com/google/cups-connector
git checkout master
package github.com/google/cups-connector/connector: cannot find package "github.com/google/cups-connector/connector" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/google/cups-connector/connector (from $GOROOT)
        /home/nw/go/src/src/github.com/google/cups-connector/connector (from $GOPATH)
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
[nw@NWCloud go]$ go env
GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/nw/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
[nw@NWCloud go]$
```

I'm using the PKGBUILD offered in the AUR, but also attempted to compile it from source from the install guide on GitHub... no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit PKGBUILD (eg when installing from aur) and replace build() function with this:

`build() {
    GOPATH="$srcdir" go get -fix -v -x ${_gourl}/gcp-cups-connector
    GOPATH="$srcdir" go get -fix -v -x ${_gourl}/gcp-cups-connector-util
}`

Also check dependencies. This PKGBUILD is missing dependecies which are: cups, net-snmp, avahi, git, bzr

Comment: Did it help you? Do you have all dependencies installed?

Comment: Thanks! It did get the build started, but then fatal error occurred.. As you mentioned in the AUR comment, I think the build structure for github changed. The process couldn't find the snmp config file.

`src/github.com/google/cups-connector/snmp/snmp.go:14:38: fatal error: net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

All dependencies are installed.

Comment: Please install that packages if you don't have them: cups, net-snmp,  avahi, git, bzr. It should solve your problem, you don't have net-snmp. After installing dependencies, install gcp-cups-connector once again.

Comment: Thank you - I had the rest, but not net-snmp as it wasn't listed on the "install" page of the github wiki or on the AUR page, but was listed on the "build from source" page, as you mentioned. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Great! Please, mark question as solved, and never trust blindly in PKGBUILDs commng from AUR ;)

Comment: Installed and running correctly thanks to you.. can you also (please) help me write a basic systemd service file to run this at boot? here is what I have... it loads correctly and seems to be running, but my printers are not avail via Google cloudprint unless I manually run ./gcp-cups-connector the directory...

`[Unit]
    Description=Google CloudPrint CUPS Connector
Requires=org.cups.cupsd.service
After=org.cups.cupsd.service network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/nw/gcp-cups-connector/usr/bin/gcp-cups-connector
StandardOutput=null
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: Now I'm maintainer of gcp-cups-connector. I fixed it and removed adding not working systemd script. I added new package with systemd service file as optdepends package `gcp-cups-connector-systemd`. Try it now.